# Pass variable with generated password from backend into frontend

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

I am trying to pass my variable with generated password into my front-end side.

I think that my main problem is that I am generating password inside

> route.post

this is my piece of **fileUpload.route.ts**

```
router.post('/upload-file', upload.array('file', 6), (req:any, res:any, next:any) => {
//...
genPass();
}
```

Inside **genPass()** is

```
let password = generator.generate({
  length: 10,
  numbers: true
});
```

I tried to do

```
module.exports = router, genPass;
```

and

```
router.get('/getpassword', fileController.fileGeneratedPassword);
```

Then inside my **Controller**

```
const password = require('../routes/fileUpload.route');

class FileController {
  public async fileGeneratedPassword(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<void> {
        console.log('pass: ' + JSON.stringify(password));
        res.json(password);
    }
}
```

But **console.log** is always empty.

How should I pass this variable?

I think that I must generate password inside **router.post** because when I upload in my frontend file then I want to generate password at the same time to "encrypt file".

I want to display generated password in my Angular frontend

Answer (score 0):

module.exports returns a single value.
you can return an object if you like but I'd separate them into 2 files

generator

```
function genPass() {
    return generator.generate({
        length: 10,
        numbers: true
    });
}

module.exports = genPass
```

controller

```
const genPass = require('generator');

class FileController {
  public async fileGeneratedPassword(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<void> {
        const password = genPass()
        console.log('pass: ' + JSON.stringify(password));
        res.json(password);
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm but now genPass is called inside controller so I can't use it after post /upload-file

Comment: you can call the function from the callback of '/upload-file'

Comment: you can either create a cache dictionary or return the password after upload.

Comment: but if is called in Controller that mean that is generated when I want it on frotend. But I need this password first on backend then send generated pass to fron

Comment: why not returning the password after the upload post method?

Comment: but when I should return it? 
for example making router.post then call inside my post  const password = genPass()
and how now export it to use somewhere else?

Comment: in your upload photo route use res.json(password)